# This image cannot currently be displayed in word

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I have a project which I'm creating word document using java and apache poi. I want to add an image in my word document but when I open the word document, I get **this image cannot currently be displayed** error.

[image: The error]

I'm adding image codes like this

```
InputStream is2=access_connection.class.getResourceAsStream("page1_header.png");
            bimg2=ImageIO.read(is2);          
            runimagetable.addPicture(is2, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imgFile2, Units.toEMU(450), Units.toEMU(200));
```

Is the error about my codes or word?

Comment: Why the `bimg2=ImageIO.read(is2);`? After that the `InputStream is2` will be at it's end and will not be able serving data in `runimagetable.addPicture(is2, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imgFile2, Units.toEMU(450), Units.toEMU(200));`. So try without the `bimg2=ImageIO.read(is2);`.

Comment: @AxelRichter It's worked,thanks.